# Polymorphism c++

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

In some books there is written that class that declares or inherits a virtual function is called a polymorphic class.

Class B doesn't have any virtual functions but passes more than one is-a test.

Class C has one virtual function but doesn't inherit.

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};

class C
{
public:
    virtual void f () {}
};
```

is class B or C polymorphic ?

Comment: Sounds like homework to me, atleast add the tag :p

Answer (score 8):

`2003: 10.3/1` states, clearly:

> A class that declares or inherits a virtual function is called a polymorphic class.

You actually said this yourself, word-for-word, so I don't really understand what the question is.

`C` (and its descendants, if you add any) is polymorphic; `A` and `B` are not.

---

<sup>Note that, in a wider OOP sense, you can always perform *some* "polymorphism" in that C++ always allows you to upcast; thus all objects that inherit can be treated as a different (but related) type.</sup>

<sup>However, the term "polymorphic" is defined slightly differently in C++, where it has more to do with whether you can *downcast* as well. If you don't want to be confusing like the C++ standard, you might call this "dynamic polymorphism".</sup>

Comment: But for a polymorphic class the destructor should be virtual, here non of the classes have a virtual destructor.

Comment: @Aditya: Yes, should be. However, the lack of a virtual destructor doesn't stop the class from being polymorphic.

Comment: @Aditya: Only if it will be deleted polymorphically.  An awful lot of classes never are.

Comment: Destructor does not have to be virtual for polymorphism. If any other function is virtual other than the destructor, that would also make the class polymorphic.

Comment: @fatma.ekici: But the object won't be destroyed polymorphically.

Answer (score 3):

Per the standard, "A class that declares or inherits a virtual function is called a polymorphic class."

Because neither `A` nor `B` declare or inherit a virtual function, they are not polymorphic.
`C` declares a virtual function, so it is polymorphic.

Answer (score 2):

`class C` is polymorphic, meaning that using `dynamic_cast` or `typeid` on a `C&` will do a runtime type check, and calling member functions through a `C&` or `C*` will use virtual dispatch.

(Of course, the as-if rule allows the compiler to avoid the runtime dispatch under some condition when it knows the runtime type in advance, such as when you just created the object.)

---

As @Bill mentioned in a comment, that isn't just what some books say, it's the definition of *polymorphic class*, found in the C++ standard (section 10.3, `[class.virtual]`):

> Virtual functions support dynamic binding and object-oriented programming.  **A class that declares or inherits a virtual function is called a *polymorphic class*.**